# Magento time zone issue - My orders are displaying different time in Sales order Grid & in created date

Tags: magento-1.9

I am getting an issue in `Magento1`.

My orders are displaying different date & time under `Sales order Grid` & `sales_flat_order`.

In admin time is Order # `100311386` | `Feb 25, 2020 11:54:01`

For same order

`sales_flat_order`, `created_at` it is `2020-02-26 04:54:01`

Now when I use `sales_flat_order`.created_at in sql query for displaying custom reports in Admin it takes `2020-02-26 04:54:01` & not `Feb 25, 2020 11:54:01`

I need to know how can I convert the database time to admin time in sql query.

Following is my query

```
SELECT
*,
pac.value AS model FROM
sales_flat_order_item AS oi,
catalog_product_entity_varchar AS pac,
sales_flat_order AS o,
catalog_product_entity_int AS pa WHERE
pac.entity_id = oi.product_id AND oi.product_id = pa.entity_id AND o.entity_id = oi.order_id AND pac.attribute_id = 145 AND pa.attribute_id = 172 AND o.created_at BETWEEN '2020-02-25 00:00:00' AND '2020-02-25 23:59:59' AND(
    IF(
        o.from_site = 'amazon',
        oi.product_type = 'simple',
        oi.product_type = 'configurable'
    )
) ORDER BY
```

Answer (score 0):

By default magento takes your defined timezone and set in database, for this date time issue you can set gmtdate everywhere you need to set date in model or controller. Please refer below code snippet for more details.

```
$model->setCreatedTime(Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
      ->setUpdateTime(Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```